# Read from a text file that does not exist in java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have some strange question but i hope for solution.

I have created a constructor in java that reads from a text file when object from constructor class is created.

If this file is exists then it reads its data even if it was empty.

but i hope for solution to handle the error of (file not exist) because this is makes my program crashes.

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Inventory{

    public Inventory(){

        Scanner x = null;
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("No current products.");
        }
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            String a = x.next(); // id
            String b = x.next(); // product name
            String c = x.next(); // product type
            String d = x.next(); // product brand
            int e = x.nextInt(); // product quantity
            int f = x.nextInt(); // production day
            int g = x.nextInt(); // production month
            int h = x.nextInt(); // production year
            int i = x.nextInt(); // expiry day
            int j = x.nextInt(); // expiry month
            int k = x.nextInt(); // expiry year
            String l = x.next(); // company name
            String m = x.next(); // supplier name
            String n = x.next(); // supplier address
            String p = x.next(); // supplier phone number
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the flow of logic in your code. Even if the file/scanner line throws an error (i.e. if the file was not found), you still attempt to read it.

The solution you're looking for is

```
Scanner x = null;
try {
    x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\products.txt"));

    while(x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next(); // id
        String b = x.next(); // product name
        String c = x.next(); // product type
        String d = x.next(); // product brand
        int e = x.nextInt(); // product quantity
        int f = x.nextInt(); // production day
        int g = x.nextInt(); // production month
        int h = x.nextInt(); // production year
        int i = x.nextInt(); // expiry day
        int j = x.nextInt(); // expiry month
        int k = x.nextInt(); // expiry year
        String l = x.next(); // company name
        String m = x.next(); // supplier name
        String n = x.next(); // supplier address
        String p = x.next(); // supplier phone number
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("No current products.");
}
```

What you should do instead of catching `Exception` is catch a specific error like [`FileNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) or, if you'd like to catch all errors, then keep it as is, but I recommend you check the error and provide more detail errors to console using something like

```
 ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.println("could not find the file...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("something else went wrong");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if your while loop is inside your `try ... catch` block, errors thrown while reading the file will also be caught.

A more explicit way to catch errors of multiple types would be

```
...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("something else went wrong");
} ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, that was really useful :)

Comment: If it works as a solution, please accept the solution as an answer.

Comment: Yes for sure it's the best solution. solution accepted :)

Comment: Why would you use `instanceof`  in a catch block? You declare the exception type for a reason -.-

Comment: @Clashsoft if you `catch (Exception ...)`, then you're catching anything that extends `Exception`, which could be anything. I'm saying /if/ he wants to catch everything explicitly in one block (i.e. not `try ... catch ... catch ...`), then do it with `instanceof`.